# how to set 'setter' of an computed property to private?

Tags: swift, setter, getter

I know how to set 'setter' of an stored property to private (e.g. `public private(set) var name: String = "John"`) but how do we set 'setter' of an computed property to private? In this case the 'setter' for the variable '`age`'. When I tried to put an keyword private in front of `set(newAge){}`, XCode display an error. So is it possible to set 'setter' of an computed property to private?

```
public class Person {

    public private(set) var name: String = "John"

    var age: Int{
        get {
            return 10
        }
        set(newAge){ // how to set this setter to private so to restrict modification

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do it the same way as for a stored property:

```
    private(set) var age: Int{
        get {
            return 10
        }
        set(newAge) {
            // setter code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome!! thank you so so much! This has been puzzling me for ages! now thanks to you, I finally got it!

Comment: Note that you can just write `set {` without naming the new value, and the new value will be accessible inside the curly brackets as `newValue`.